# will a partition wall float?

Tags: walls, construction, carpentry

While replacing some burnt lumber I found a partition wall sitting perpendicularly atop two 2x8 joists.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I need to remove said joists and the subfloor above them back to the carrier beam.

I'm thinking of removing the base plates on either side of the doorway to acomplish my goal.

Will the wall hang, or will it need support?

How would you support this wall, without interfering with the path the new for joists must take to get underneath it?

Comment: Do you feel lucky?  Most walls have a few nails driven into the ceiling joists to hold the wall straight up.  They might hold the wall up as you are working under it or not.  I would bet on the not..  It will depend on how much of the bottom support you remove, a few joists no big deal, all support under the wall bigger deal.  Pictures will help.

Comment: The word 'this' in the first paragraph is a hyperlink to some detailed photos. Let me know if I can provide anything else

Comment: Is that a decorative(non support) beam on the top right?

Comment: Negative, that's a 16ft lvl that's redirecting the roof load to the basement floor/ the other good half of the first floor. I should have included that info

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/gallery/ZPTD5rV) is the adjecent wall

Comment: That makes life more interesting.  Is the support post under the wall just for holding the wall up or providing support for that beam also?  Might just be faster to remove that wall, replace joists and sub floor, then put the wall back up.  Good chance the drywall will crack anyway.

Comment: @crip659 Yeah it does lol From what I can tell, the two floor joists are just centered under this wall for support. The screw jack is just something I placed to test a theory.  The lvl is independently carrying the rafter load to the basement via 8x 2x6's laminated together, also of note is that the lvl cuts through the double top plate of the floating partition wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for sure about "will it hold" but for

> How would you support this wall, without interfering with the path the new for joists must take to get underneath it?

I'd screw an unused joist into every stud across the entire length of the wall and support it at both ends. Looks like you could use that temporary beam on the outside end to hang it. You should know best where something solid remains on the inside end.

Comment: The drywall is in the way.  I think OP is trying to limit damage to the drywall, but it should be the easiest way to remove some drywall and repair after.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're thinking something like [THIS](https://imgur.com/gallery/G3YSM2T) where I trim a 10ft 2x8 rectangle out of the dry wall, cross brace it on one side and drop 2x6 supports onto a base plate secured to the basement floor. Where I could then remove the subfloor/ bottom plates of the wall and tip the new floor joists in from the other side..

Comment: @David I meant screwing over/through the drywall. There should be no need to remove it, you're not holding up that much weight, assuming you checked this wasn't a load bearing wall. A bunch of large screws or small lag bolts will hold it fine through drywall. Think of it as the opposite of installing a TV mount.

Comment: @Olivier Thank you, it *shouldn't* be a load bearing wall, its parallel to the joists,   I looked at the stud layout and it's a 2x4 king/ jack in the doorway with 16" o.c. studs. I cut a portion of the bottom plate on the right under a stud and didn't notice any sag. It's a split level house so I made sure that it's the wall parallel to the one I'm working on that's carrying the gable roof, I'm not sure how/ what else to check

Comment: @Olivier [this](https://imgur.com/gallery/yJfRs11) is roughly what I'm thinking/seeing

Comment: @David It's still suspicious with the doubled joist under it. But you seem to have done reasonable checks. Proceed carefully (ie. remove the support slowly, watch and listen for signs of trouble, don't stay under the wall, have someone nearby to get help if things go south).